# Symfony2 DIC > Why services class are not proxied?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

I really love the Symfony2 DIC stuff, service XML configurator is easy to use. BUT, when I declare a new service, for instance :

```
<service id="form.csrf_provider" class="Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\SessionCsrfProvider">
  <argument type="service" id="session"/>
  <argument>ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt</argument>
</service>
```

Session will be automatically created if I call

```
$container->get('form.csrf_provider')
```

Even if I dont use it at all (Twig does it even if you don't use it Form..), and as cascade effect, lot of services class are created and never used ! Thats cost a lot.

I know doctrine use the proxy pattern for entity, the entity is not loaded less you call

```
$entity->getTitle() // etc....
```

They really should do the same thing for services class (only in production env of course), that will improve Symfony2 a lot. My current solution is to pass the container itself as argument, but it breaks the DIC goal ;-(

Anyone has other solution ? thanks

Comment: There's an idea to implement lazy service loading in DIC: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5012